# Erro ao serializar com namespace em if

Tags: c#, xml

Estava serializando um arquivo e funcionava normal, porém agora, ao serializar aparece q1 em todas as tags, estou fazendo desta forma:

```c#
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter tw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);

        XmlSerializerNamespaces xsn = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GerarNfseEnvio));
        FileStream arquivo = new FileStream("E:\\NFSe-" + "RPS" + numero.ToString().PadLeft(15, '0') + ".xml", FileMode.CreateNew);
        if (item.CodigoMunicipio == 3107109)
        {
            xsn.Add("", "http://www.betha.com.br/e-nota-contribuinte-ws");
        }
        else
        {
            xsn.Add("", "http://www.abrasf.org.br/nfse.xsd");
        }
        ser.Serialize(arquivo, gerar, xsn);
        arquivo.Close();
```

Funcionava perfeitamente, porém agora as tags aparecem assim:

```
<q1:GerarNfseEnvio xmlns="http://www.betha.com.br/e-nota-contribuinte-ws" xmlns:q1="http://www.abrasf.org.br/nfse.xsd">
```

Ele está adicionando as duas, só quando eu deixo somente a linha  `xsn.Add("", "http://www.abrasf.org.br/nfse.xsd");` que dá certo. Estava funcionando perfeitamente. Após adicionar o if, ficou desta forma. Como corrigir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voceê pode salvar o segundo parâmetro numa variável. Deve funcionar dessa forma:

```
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    XmlTextWriter tw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);

    XmlSerializerNamespaces xsn = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GerarNfseEnvio));
    FileStream arquivo = new FileStream("E:\\NFSe-" + "RPS" + numero.ToString().PadLeft(15, '0') + ".xml", FileMode.CreateNew);
    String url = "http://www.abrasf.org.br/nfse.xsd";
    if (item.CodigoMunicipio == 3107109)
    {
        url = "http://www.betha.com.br/e-nota-contribuinte-ws";
    }
    xsn.Add("", url);

    ser.Serialize(arquivo, gerar, xsn);
    arquivo.Close();
```

Comment: Não resolve, continua aparecendo da mesma forma `<q1:GerarNfseEnvio xmlns="http://www.betha.com.br/e-nota-contribuinte-ws" xmlns:q1="http://www.abrasf.org.br/nfse.xsd">` como se não tivesse o `if`

Comment: Ok, nao podia comentar antes pq nao tenho pontos suficientes. O que vc pode tentar é usar o namespace padrão como [segundo parametro do construtor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.-ctor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_Serialization_XmlSerializer__ctor_System_Type_System_String_) e adicionar o `betha.com.br....` com o `xsn.Add`no if